# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rfloor!}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left\lfloor \dfrac{n+1}{2} \right\rfloor!}{n!}$$

I tried Stirling's formula but I seem to get nowhere. How should I proceed?

Comment: $[(n+1)/2]< (n+1)/2+1<(n-1)$ for $n>5$

Answer (score 4):

As $\lfloor \frac{n+1}2\rfloor <n$ for $n\ge2$, we have $\lfloor \frac{n+1}2\rfloor\le (n-1)!=\frac1n\cdot n!$

Comment: I think you are missing a " ! ", and how do you get to the second inequality anyway?

Comment: It is because if $m$ and $M$ are non-negative integers with $m\le M$, then $m!\le M!$ (and $\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor \le n-1$).